# Replace Template String with Current Date and Time in Vim

Tags: bash, vim, date, templates

I have a template file with the following string:

```
{{date}} {{time24}} Some text.
```

I want to replace `{{date}} {{time}}` with the current date and time on a keymap.

I currently have:

```
:nnoremap <leader>d :%s@{{date}} {{time24}}@\=system('/path/to/script.sh')@<CR><CR>
```

In the script, I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" | tr -d '\n'
```

The problem I am running into is that this brings in text from my `.bashrc`.

Is there a way to accomplish this from within vim itself or an easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, see `:help date-functions`.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to find additional help from https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Insert_current_date_or_time as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you could do it all in one place:

```
nnoremap <leader>d :s/{{date}}\s*{{time24}}/\=strftime("%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")<CR>
```

where…

- you don't have to maintain a separate script,
- you avoid any potential side-effect of `:source`-ing a script (delay, non-existing file, autocommands, etc.),
- you only use one substitution,
- and one call to `strftime()`.

Comment: While my intent was to maintain a separate script file, I accepted this answer for keeping things within vim's own default environment. I could simplify my script of course to make a single call to `strftime()` and a single substitution, using the substitution in your answer.

Thank you for your help and feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a vimscript file (foo.txt) with the following text:

```
:s/{{date}}/\=strftime("%Y%m%d")/

:s/{{time24}}/\=strftime("%H:%M:%S")/
```

These two commands are sed commands which replace the template strings with the time in a string format, specified by standard date and time variables for format. The first covers the date; the second covers the time.

I have changed my keymap to the following:

```
:nnoremap <leader>d :source! /path/to/foo.vim<CR>
```

Here, in normal mode, I trigger a non-recursive remap on typing my keybinding, in this case, `leader d`, with `d` standing for date. This keybinding performs a source command that executes the script given above, which then executes each command in sequence, replacing first the date and then the time.

Now the date and time are replaced without issue.

Comment: What a contrived "solution".

Comment: This could be added all to a single line I am sure. My intent was to keep scripting in files outside my current environment.